# Set attributes types when query fetches data

Tags: php, database, types

I noticed that if I register anything in my database, no matter what the variable type is, it will be stocked as a string in it.

When I fetch it with a query, I will also get a string instead of an integer, a boolean, or whatever.

```php
    $var = 1;

    $query = $dao->prepare('INSERT INTO table SET var = :var');
    $query->bindValue('var', $var, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();

    $query = $dao->prepare('SELECT var FROM table');
    $query->execute();
    var_dump($query->fetchColumn()); // (string) "1" instead of (int) 1
```

It is kind of annoying because I have to be careful when comparing my data type with some values.

I am using OOP. My Entity objects hydrate themselves when passing an array to their constructor, checking and setting their types while doing so.

Unfortunatly, when I fetch data from my database, I am using `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` const, so my objects attributes are set, but they are all string since the class constructor is not being used.

How do devs handle this?